# 特定の条件下においてのアニメーション処理

Tags: swift

起動時にアニメーション処理が行われ、ボタンを押した時に再びアニメーション処理を行うといった動作がしたい場合、どのようにコーディングしていけばいいでしょうか？

```js
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func actionButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        //ここにアニメーションの動作を書きたい。

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        imageView.hidden = false
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)
        //8.0秒間で位置を変える
        UIView.animateWithDuration(8.0, delay:0.5,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animations: {() -> Void in
                //アニメーションの処理
                self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)},
            completion:{(Bool) -> Void in})
    }
}
```

１回目(起動時)のアニメーション処理のコードは書けたのですが、
ボタンを押した時のアニメーション処理が分からず・・・
クロージャをはずして書き込もうと思ったのですが、動作できず失敗しました。

ちなみにアニメーション処理は

```js
//起動時(アニメーション前)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)

//起動時(アニメーション後)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 400, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)

//ボタンを押した時のアニメーション処理
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)
```

お詳しい方がいましたらご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func actionButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(8.0, delay:0.5,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: {() -> Void in
            //アニメーションの処理
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 37, width: 240, height: 377)},
        completion:{(Bool) -> Void in})
}
```

問題を深く考えすぎのように見えます。話は単純で、「UIView.animate」以下、そのまま書き写せばいいのです。
なお、このコードはむだな部分が多くあります。次のように書きかえることができます。

```
@IBAction func actionButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(8.0, delay: 0.5,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
        animations: {self.imageView.center = CGPoint(x: 220, y: 225.5)},
        completion: nil)
}
```

Closureは、引数と返り値を使わないのであれば、省略可能。
メソッド「animation〜」の引数「completion」は、「completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)」となっており、オプショナル型なので、使わなければnilを入れておくことができます。
ビューの移動は、プロパティcenter（CGPoint）を変更するだけです。frame（CGRect）を使うより、入力する値が少なく、人為的なミスを減らすことができます。

Comment: ご回答してくださったコードを打ってビルドしてみると、起動時のimageViewは(x:100,y:37)に動くのですが、
ボタンを押すと(x:100,y:37)に向けてimageViewが動いてしまい、imageViewが外から画面内へ映る動きとは少し違うようです。
上記してくださったコードの両方で試したみたのですが、これは起動時に移動した後のimageViewの値を定義しておいた方がいいのでしょうか？

Comment: わたしは、あなたの質問における、プログラムの説明を、「ボタンをタップしたら、imageViewの左上角の座標を、(400, 37)から(100, 37)に移動するアニメーション」と理解しました。それがあなたの意図と異なるなら、わたしの理解力より、あなたの説明のしかたのほうに問題があると思います。こういういい方はしたくないんですが……
ともあれ、座標の位置の問題に過ぎないのであれば、あなたが数値を書きかえればいいだけの話です。
また、いってこいの、往復のアニメーションを、じつはしたいというのでしたら、新規に質問をたててください。ご自身の質問を3度読み直して、誤解が生まれないように。

Comment: えっと…説明が不十分で申し訳なかったのですが、数値を入れ替える云々の話ではなく、質問で記載した「override func viewDidAppear」のコードがあると、そっちの方の処理結果である(x:100,y:37)に依存してしまうみたいなので、「override func viewDidAppear」を使わずにコードを書いていった方がいいのでしょうか、ということです。
つまり、往復云々の話ではなく、「override func viewDidAppear」を定義した上での回答者様のコードを試してみると、数値を入れ替えたとしても動作的に位置がずれてしまう、ということです。
お分かりいただけたでしょうか？長くなってしまって申し訳ないのですが、読んで頂けると幸いです。

Comment: まだ、あなたの意図を把握できていません。  
（以下、imageViewの座標は、左上隅を指します）  
(1) アプリ起動時、imageViewは、(100, 37)にある。  
(2) アプリ起動0.5秒後、imageViewは、8秒間かけて(400, 37)に移動する。  
(3) ボタンを押すと、imageViewは、8秒間かけて(400, 37)から、(100, 37)に移動する。  
わたしは、あなたの意図を、こう理解しています。違いがあれば指摘してください。  
  
※Storyboard上で、Auto Layoutを有効にしていると、Storyboardにおけるオブジェクトのレイアウトと、プログラムによるオブジェクトの位置指定が、「見た目」ずれることがあります。もしこのことなら、UIViewのアニメーションはまったく関係のない話になります。

Comment: 問題の解釈については回答者様の把握しているもので間違いありません。ちなみにUse Auto Layoutを解除したら成功しました！ただ単に私が初心者で上手く状況を説明できなかったのが問題でしたね……何度もお時間をかけさせてしまって申し訳ないです。有り難うございました！

Comment: 「ひょっとして？」が命中しましたか……
これを機会に、Auto Layoutについて、すこし勉強なさることをお勧めします。ごぞんじのように、iPhoneの画面サイズだけでも、4種類（Retinaもいれると、それ以上）あります。扱いのむずかしいAuto Layoutですが、これを有効に使い回さないと、ユーザにそっぽをむかれるアプリしか作れなくなります。

Comment: そうですね、勉強してみます！ありがとうございました。